# The wrap_content for height doesn't work in LinearLayout childView

Tags: android, android-layout

**I want** to add view's to `LinearLayout` programmatically. I create views inflated from xml (with `layout_height="wrap_content"`) and then I add this views to `LinearLayout`.

**But** when I run my app I see only one child view in my `LinearLayout` and height of this view is match_parent (the child view fill all `LinearLayout`).

How to fix it?

**My code:**
Add child views to `LinearLayout`:

```
llContent.removeAllViewsInLayout()
for (i in 1..4) {
    val view = nextCellView(context!!) // here I create my childView
    llContent.addView(view)
}
```

In nextCellView() ... I create this view:

```
abstract class AbsModuleCellView : FrameLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        initView()
    }
    // ... all empty constructors with initView() call

    @LayoutRes
    protected abstract fun obtainLayoutResId(): Int

    private fun initView() {
        inflateViewContent(obtainLayoutResId())
    }

    private fun inflateViewContent(@LayoutRes layoutResId: Int) {
        obtainInflater().inflate(layoutResId, this)
    }

    private fun obtainInflater() = context.provideLayoutInflater()
}
```

**And xml**:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
```

And for every created childView I apply this `layoutParams`:

```
childView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

And every child view is class which extends `FrameLayout` and in xml the root view is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlBaseModuleCell"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
    tools:ignore="KeyboardInaccessibleWidget">
```

Comment: have tried without `layoutParams` ? if tried then what happened ?

Comment: @duggu yes, I tried, but it doesn't help me

Comment: doesnt help me means still u can able add only one view ?

Comment: @duggu I can add all my childViews but I see only one view because it's height all parent height

Comment: can u please change `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` this to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` ...

Comment: Hhow do you inflate the child views? Post that code.

Comment: @duggu I tried it but it doesn't help me ((

Comment: @BenP. added code